# How can i remove an image with non-data pixels from an MODIS image collection

Tags: google-earth-engine

I would like to calculate my index using MODIS LST products. To do that, I am going to ignore the images with non-data pixels by removing from an image collection. It means I would like to filter the image collection to keep only images which have the values in all pixels. Could you please guide me about how I can do it?